# css working sporadically in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

[image]I have extra style sheets to try and fix loathsome IE, however there are a few images I cannot get to budge. The little icon images on this page http://www.sporttours.net/news/ next to the news items show up over the sidebar art "Sport Tours". I can affect the images by adding red borders, hiding them totally and a few other things. However, I can't affect margin or padding to try and move them over. Anyone have any suggestions? And yes, they want it to work perfectly in IE too (HA!) so I can't just let it be.

Comment: what version(s) of IE are you testing?

Answer (score 2):

First [validate your HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.sporttours.net/news/&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) - as you can see its ridden with errors.

Validation shows you're missing a doctype - add one!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: To go off of this: A valid doctype helps fix a lot of errors in IE, granted there could be quite a bit still even after a doctype, but it should also help you get in the right direction.

Comment: Actually, there is a doctype in the page, but there is also some code inserted above the doctype (a stray `<div>` tag and a `<script>` block). These will make the doctype invalid. The doctype **must** be the first thing in the page -- even a blank line or comment above it can make it invalid. As this answer says, fix that, and you'll fix most of your IE-specific issues. Then use the validator he linked to, and see what other bugs you have in your code. Every bug picked up by the validator is likely to cause cross-browser quirks.